# What is the convention for using symbols like @, ~, #, etc. for path aliases in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, eslint, monorepo

In a recent project, in the `tsconfig.json`, I found path aliases using the symbol `@`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@/pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      ...
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "jest.config.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

But in some online videos and articles, I have also seen the usage of symbols like `~` and `#`.

My questions are:

1. Is there a convention on what symbol shall be used in case of filesystems, typescript modules, assets, static files, and other file types?
2. If so, is there an eslint rule or plugin that is available to enforce importing using these rules?

Couldn't find the answer for this in TypeScript documentation and simple web search.

Comment: No, there isn't any convention. I tend to use `#` since `@` can be confused for a module scope and `~` can be confused for the *actual* root directory.

Comment: @caTS any eslint plugin that can enforce such kind of rules?

Comment: Why would you need to enforce it? If the path is incorrect you'll get an error at compile time.

Comment: What i meant was let's say in a project, I would like to make people use path aliases only and not relative paths.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276530/how-to-enable-absolute-path-aliases-with-eslint-import-plugin-in-a-typescript-re) and [this](https://github.com/msfragala/eslint-plugin-path-alias)?

Comment: @caTS Thanks. The above links should work for me. But for convention part, I feel there should be a common rule since it creates a bit of confusion when landing on a new project and not make people hop to tsconfig every time for this.

Comment: @EternalObserver you can provide suggestions/feature requests to TypeScript here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/

Comment: @cuuupid It's more like a rule for eslint-typescript !